# MySQL update using PDO with variable

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm having a strange problem with php PDO and mysql.
I read other examples here, but while I am learning MySQL with the PDO, I did not understand it and I could not solve it yet.

```
$name = $_POST[ "name" ];
$email = $_POST[ "email" ];
$telefone = $_POST[ "telefone" ];
$endereco = $_POST[ "endereco" ];
$numero = $_POST[ "numero" ];
$bairro = $_POST[ "bairro" ];
$cidade = $_POST[ "cidade" ];

$telefoneHash = make_hash( $telefone );

$PDO = db_connect();

//$PDO->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
//With this code it gives the error: 'Syntax error or access violation: 1064'
//Without it it does not give an error but does not perform the update

$PDO = $PDO->prepare( 'UPDATE users SET :name, :email, :telefone, :endereco, :numero, :bairro, :cidade WHERE email = :email' ); 

$PDO->bindValue( ':name', $_REQUEST[ 'name' ] );
$PDO->bindValue( ':email', $_REQUEST[ 'email' ] );
$PDO->bindValue( ':telefone', $telefoneHash );
$PDO->bindValue( ':endereco', $_REQUEST[ 'endereco' ] );
$PDO->bindValue( ':numero', $_REQUEST[ 'numero' ] );
$PDO->bindValue( ':bairro', $_REQUEST[ 'bairro' ] );
$PDO->bindValue( ':cidade', $_REQUEST[ 'cidade' ] );
$PDO->execute();

echo $PDO->rowCount() . " records UPDATED successfully";
```

Comment: that isn't how it works.

Comment: And in other examples that you read `UPDATE` syntax is the same as yours?

Comment: A.) Your update query is incorrect. 2.) You should be using an INSERT instead of an UPDATE....maybe iii.) There is no need to change to `$_REQUEST` if your variables are set at the top of the page.

Comment: @JayBlanchard `INSERT instead of an UPDATE`. With a `where` clause? Lack of coffee again?

Comment: You're creating a bunch of variables that serve no purpose here as well. PDO also allows you to fire a single `execute` call with an associative array that has all the values, that helps cut down on how much code you have to write.

Comment: @u_mulder I said. "...maybe" ;-)

Comment: You may want to start by using an ORM like [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/), [Propel](http://propelorm.org/), or 
[Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent) which can help guide you through the process of creating, retrieving, updating, and deleting records. Until you've learned all of the SQL fundamentals this can be a bit daunting. An ORM gives you a gentler introduction, but won't limit you when you understand more, you can always coach the ORM better with more specific SQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax for UPDATE with PDO is `SET col=:col`

Using the column name, followed by the equal sign and the named placeholder.

```
$PDO = $PDO->prepare( 'UPDATE users SET name = :name, email = :email, 
                       telefone = :telefone, endereco = :endereco, 
                       numero = :numero, bairro = :bairro, cidade = :cidade 
                       WHERE email = :email' );
```

PDO error handling would have clearly shown you the errors:

- https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php

Use error reporting also.

- https://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

This assuming that the column names are of the same names that I used here.

However and as stated, why use the `$_REQUEST`'s? Just use the variables that you assigned in the POST arrays, and assuming that your form is using a post method.

```
$PDO->bindValue(':name', $name);
$PDO->bindValue(':email', $email);
$PDO->bindValue(':telefone', $telefoneHash);
$PDO->bindValue(':endereco', $telefone);
$PDO->bindValue(':numero', $numero);
$PDO->bindValue(':bairro', $bairro);
$PDO->bindValue(':cidade', $cidade);
$PDO->execute();
```

Comment: u_mulder pointed out another in his answer about the email placeholder; I'm not worthy ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Base `UPDATE` query syntax is

```
UPDATE `table_name` SET field_name = FIELD_VALUE
```

So, in your query you should do:

```
$PDO = $PDO->prepare( 'UPDATE users SET name = :name, email = :email /* more fields here */ WHERE email = :email2' ); 

$PDO->bindValue( ':name', $_REQUEST[ 'name' ] );
$PDO->bindValue( ':email', $_REQUEST[ 'email' ] );
$PDO->bindValue( ':email2', $_REQUEST[ 'email' ] );
// more binds here
$PDO->execute();

echo $PDO->rowCount() . " records UPDATED successfully";
```

First note: you can't use same placeholder name twice, that's why I replaced `:email` with `:email2`.

Second note: I suppose, it's useless to update `email` by which you find the record to the same value.